# unable to send email through PHP with POP3

Tags: php, pop3

I have completed writing a PHP code in order to send email with POP3. But every time I am being faced by an error

> [error] => Connecting to the POP3 server raised a PHP warning: 
>       [errno] => 2
>       [errstr] => fsockopen() [function.fsockopen]: unable to connect to pop3.yahoo.com:465 (A connection attempt failed )
>   SMTP -> ERROR: Failed to connect to server: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time,

Here is my code.

```
<?php
require_once('/class.phpmailer.php');
require_once('/class.pop3.php'); // required for POP before SMTP

$pop = new POP3();
$pop->Authorise('pop3.yahoo.com',465,10, 'arsalansherwani@yahoo.com',     
'******',1);

$mail = new PHPMailer();
$msg='Name';
//$body             = file_get_contents('contents.html');
//$body             = eregi_replace("[\]",'',$body);
$address='arsalanjawed619.com';
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPDebug = 1;
$mail->Host     = 'pop3.yahoo.com';

$mail->SetFrom('arsalansherwani@yahoo.com', 'arsalan');

$mail->AddReplyTo("arsalansherwani@yahoo.com","arsalan");

$mail->Subject    = "PHPMailer Test Subject via POP before SMTP, basic";

$mail->AltBody    = "To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!";       

$mail->MsgHTML($msg);

$address = "arsalanjawed619@yahoo.com";
$mail->AddAddress($address, "arsalan");

//$mail->AddAttachment("images/phpmailer.gif");      // attachment
//$mail->AddAttachment("images/phpmailer_mini.gif"); // attachment


if(!$mail->Send()) {
echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
echo "Message sent!";
}
?>
```

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 4):

You don't send emails with pop3, this is to retrieve them. You send emails with SMTP for example...

Answer (score 1):

you are connecting to wrong server. connect to smtp server. i think below code will work.

```
 $pop->Authorise('smtp.mail.yahoo.com',465,10, 'arsalansherwani@yahoo.com',     
 '******',1);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use different server for POP3 and SMTP.

POP3 is for receiving email

SMTP is for sending email

You need to use

`$mail->Host= 'smtp.mail.yahoo.com';`

instead of

`$mail->Host = pop3.yahoo.com';`

and

`$pop->Authorise('pop3.yahoo.com',465,10, 'arsalansherwani@yahoo.com',

'******',1);`

to

`$pop->Authorise('pop.mail.yahoo.com',465,10,'arsalansherwani@yahoo.com',

'******',1);`

respectively to make it work

```
<?php
require_once('class.phpmailer.php');/*Including classes from php mailer*/
require_once('class.pop3.php'); 
require_once('class.smtp.php');
$pop = new POP3(); /*Create a new object for pop3*/
$pop->Authorise('mailserver001.mydomain.com', 110, 30, 'username', 'password', 1); /*login in to pop3 */
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->Debugoutput = 'html';
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
$mail->SMTPOptions = array(
                'ssl' => array(
                'verify_peer' => false,
                'verify_peer_name' => false,
                'allow_self_signed' => true)
               ); /*Skip SSL Errors(if any),generally not needed*/
$mail->Host     = 'mailserver001.mydomain.com'; /*SMTP host*/
$mail->SetFrom('info@mydomain.com', 'Name');/*Email content */
$mail->AddReplyTo("info@mydomain.com","Name");
$mail->Subject    = "Welcome";
$mail->AltBody    = "To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!"; 
$mail->MsgHTML('HTML');
$address = "myname@otherdomain.com";
$mail->AddAddress($address, "Name");
if(!$mail->Send()) {/*Send Email*/
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
echo "Message sent!";
}  
?>
```

To enable POP3 for a free Yahoo Mail account:

Go to the Gear and click Settings:

Click the Accounts navigation, then click the Edit button:

Click the Radio Button for POP, select if you want Spam included, and then click Save:

After turning on POP3 the settings for Yahoo Mail are:

Incoming mail server settings:

**Free Yahoo Accounts: pop.mail.yahoo.com (port 995, requires SSL)**

**Yahoo Plus Accounts: plus.pop.mail.yahoo.com (port 995, requires SSL)**

Use your full email address and password for your login.

**Free Yahoo Mail accounts should use the outgoing server setting: smtp.mail.yahoo.com, port 587 (requires SSL/TLS)**

Comment: Please elaborate your changes.

Comment: `$mail->Host     = 'pop3.yahoo.com';`

Comment: change above line to smtp.yahoo.com

Answer (score 0):

pop3 is postoffice protocol required to retrive emails from an mail server. you need to use smtp protocol. connect to an smtp server with proper authorization. some smtp server may require ssl